# Eclipse marvin classpath

Tags: java, eclipse

I'll keep it short.
I have a project in eclipse using Marvin, the Marvin's jar is added correctly in the build path, classpath.
The problem is, whenever me or someone else exports the project from github and open it in eclipse they have to edit Marvin's Jar path in classpath or to re add it.
I tried to search everywhere for a solution.
Is there one? I don't know. Something like:
new File("src/file.txt")
And then using file.getAbsolutePath() and getting the entire path including the directory (D:\project\src\file.txt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load JAR files dynamically at Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-to-load-jar-files-dynamically-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to an external build tool, like Maven or Gradle, that will download it for you on whatever machine you're on, or make your Java Build Path reference portable by using a [classpath variable](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-classpath-variables.htm?cp=1_2_1_0_2) that you then manually assign on each Eclipse workspace.

Comment: I just want a simple method to add the .jar (Marvin) into the classpath at runtime so that I can use the classes within it (MarvinImage x = new MarvinImage)... I have the .jar file downloaded why is it so hard to add it dynamically/locally without the use of the internet?